# How to get videoWork data of GnAcrMatch's tvAiring in Gracenote Entourage SDK?

Tags: gracenote

I am a commercial developer of Gracenote. I want to get videoWork data of GnAcrMatch's tvAiring after the SDK giving me some matches when detecting a video. For example, in the result event I run this code in the resultEvent callback of IGnAcrEvents implementation:

```
GnTVAiring tvAiring = acrMatch.tvAiring();
                    if (!tvAiring.isNull())
                    {
                        GnTitle subtitle = acrMatch.subtitle();
                        GnTVChannel tvChannel = tvAiring.tvChannel();

                        updateResultView(
                                String.format("Airing: %s(%s) %s %s (Match #%d)",
                                        officialTitle,
                                        (subtitle != null ? subtitle.display() : "n/a"),
                                        (tvChannel != null ? tvChannel.channelCallsign() : "n/a"),
                                        matchPosition,
                                        matchCounter),
                                false);
                        System.out.println("tvAiring is not null");

                        GnVideoWork videoWork = tvAiring.tvProgram().videoWork();
                        System.out.println("Release date: " + videoWork.dateOriginalRelease());
                    }
```

This code just print "Release date: ", although It has recognized a movie on live TV.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a valid 'videoWork'?
Not all TV Program has a corresponding video work so I am guessing that there is none available.
Next time if you have a similar problem please also specify the GNID of the TV Program so it can be verified easily.

- If you are already a commercial developer then it may be faster to reach out to your Gracenote contact regarding your questions.